# Compute the contour integral $∫_{|z|=1} \frac{e^{i(1+z)}}{z^{10}}dz$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Compute the contour integral $$∫_{|z|=1} \frac{e^{i(1+z)}}{z^{10}}dz$$

I am stuck at solving the integral. 
I know there is a singularity at z=0 and therefore we cannot apply the Cauchy Theorem directly. 
I used the parametrization $z=e^{it}$ and $dz=ie^{it}$ where $R=1$.

However my integration resulted into a mess and i cannot seem to reach the final answer.

Comment: Have you learned the Residue Theorem?

Comment: No i haven't learnt the residue theorem yet. We have learnt the generalized Cauchy theorem though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy integral formula, we have that if $f(z)$ is holomorphic inside $\gamma$ and $a$ is inside $\gamma$, then
$$f^{(n)}(a) = \dfrac{n!}{(2 \pi i)}\int_{\gamma} \dfrac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}} dz$$
In our case, $f(z) = \exp(i) \exp(iz)$, $n = 9$, $a = 0$ and $\gamma$ is the contour $\vert z \vert = 1$.

Also, recall that $$\dfrac{d^n (\exp(az))}{dz^n} = a^n \exp(az)$$
Now you should be able to get your answer.